# how to get access token in facebook SDK

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-sdk-4.0

I m curently developing a laravel website in which i m using facebook sdk, I installed the facebook sdk in my project and i created a facebook app and i activate it but i don't know when i wrote my php code i got null token.
I m using laravel 5.2 and facebook Sdk v 5.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use  Facebook;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Facebook\FacebookRequset;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException ;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException ;
 use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    { 
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([

  'app_id' => 'myAppId',
  'app_secret' => 'mySecretCode', 
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6'
]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
   $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
   dd($accessToken);



try {


  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name',$accessToken );


} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();

 dd( $me);

$user = $fb->getUser(); 

        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: use this package https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk

Comment: the problem is in this package there is no share function